# How can I extract TP, FN, FP from classification_report

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I know I can output the contents of the sklearn `classification_report` as a `dict` and extract micro/macro averaged scores along with scores for individual labels.

How can I get the counts for the associated confusion matrix inputs, specifically, `TP`, `FN`, and `FP` that go into the computations for the macro averaged measures? I have my vectors for `y_pred` and `y_true`, so I assume there is a way to get the desired parameters I want.

This is for a binary classification problem, but I will also need it for a multiclass task, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: 
`tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix([0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0]).ravel()`

and `sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix`